# Is it possible to make VictoryPie Slices overlap on each other?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

I'm using the [Victory Pie](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-pie/) in my React Native app and it renders fine without any issues, but my requirement is that each slice within the pie chart should be have circular corners and overlap on each other like in the image:

[image]

I'm able to get the circular corners by applying the attribute:

```
cornerRadius
```

but is it possible to make them overlap like in the picture or should I create a custom component?

Comment: Hi @venky, Are you able to find solution for this, I am having same requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into same issue, here's my workaround:

You have to override Victory's data component and create an overlap by increasing endAngle a bit.

Example below also shows how to achieve circular shape of slices.

```
function CustomSlice(props: SliceProps) {
    const { datum } = props;

    const sliceOverride = {
        ...props.slice,
        endAngle: (props.slice?.endAngle ?? 0) + 0.3,
    };
    return (
        <Slice {...props}
               slice={sliceOverride}
               cornerRadius={50}
               sliceStartAngle={datum.background ? 0 : props.sliceStartAngle}
               sliceEndAngle={datum.background ? 360 : props.sliceStartAngle} />
   );
}
/* ... */
<VictoryPie dataComponent={CustomSlice} />
```

Result for [2, 1, 1] data values:

[image: Result]

Answer (score -1):

This answer is quite late, but after a tone of searching the only solution I could find to this was to create a second `<VictoryPie>` graph and have it resting directly underneath the graph you are wanting the background color for.

This solution only worked for having a single background + color and not multiple like you required in your example though.

Comment: Welcome to the site. While this may be an answer it would be a better answer if you shared code on how this was done.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).